# Why does Ruby parse 'foo' into 01.01.1970 within a Date type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do have a model within a Rails application with the following definition (I am using Mongoid):

`field :date, type: Date`

I included the field within the view as a text_field (f.text_field). Everything works fine, if I do enter a valid date. But when I enter some text in this field (e.g. 'foo'), then the date gets parsed as 01.01.1970. I am not parsing the date manually, rather I use the following code:

`@offer = Offer.new(offer_params)`

I also checked on the Ruby console:

```
>> offer = Offer.new
...

>> offer.date = 'foo'
"foo"

>> offer.date
Thu, 01 Jan 1970

>> offer.date.is_a? Date
true
```

How can I prevent this behavior so that the record can't be saved and a validation error gets shown to the user?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the Offer initializer so that it will use the [Date::parse](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) method for parsing your date. This will throw an ArgumentError, when the parameter you supply to it is not a valid date format.

You may have to convert that to seconds since 1.1.1970 as that seems to be the format used for storing your dates in your database. Have a look at [Date#strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) for that.

Comment: Ok. But shouldn't that somehow be handled by ActiveRecord / Mongoid? Guess that is not an uncommon case that the user may enter a date into a text field and the app needs to parse it.